# ASP.NET adding Authentication to Report Handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, httphandler, activereports

I've got a Active Reports Handler configured on my website so that i can open the Report directly over a link e.g.

```
http://localhost/Report.rdlx?OutputFormat=pdf
```

The problem now of course is that there is no authentication so that everyone can call this link.

**How can I add authentication check to this handler?**

I am using Forms authentication, preferably I'd like to also check if the user is in a certain role, but would be happy with `IsAuthenticated` check - so that the user at least has to be logged in to see the report.

I tried to build a "reverse proxy" route handler (I'm using MVC) that returns the response from the report URL only if the user is authenticated. But this doesn't solve the problem since the "original" URL is still exposed.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the ASP.NET authorization control, meaning you can limit access to that location in the web.config file
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871